# How do I send a put request to my API with just a button or a div?

Tags: javascript, rest, laravel, reactjs, put

I have a web app right now which renders a list of items.

Basically on a div click, I want to send a put request that just modifies the likes value of my JSON object.

This is the structure right now for my data:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "test-1",
        "description": "test-1",
        "likes": [
            "username-1",
            "username-2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "test-2",
        "description": "test-2",
        "likes": [
            "username-1",
            "username-2"
        ]
    }
```

So all of these are being rendered at the same time, and each of them are gonna have a like button on the side. When someone clicks on that like button, I'd like to send a put request to my API that modifies the JSON object with the same id by adding their username to the "likes".

Any help is appreciated Thnaks

Comment: just attach an onClick event to the button and in that function make the put request

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Send the PUT request asynchronously to your API (via JQuery for example) then wait the response from the API if it was success or not, then retrive the new JSON data.
2. Send the PUT request asynchronously to your API and force the JSON data to include the new username to the likes data.

The first option is better as it handles all changes (new likes or likes removed) made by other users.

In JQuery to do so, you could use the following code on your "on click" event handling:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // Use POST with X-HTTP-Method-Override or directly a PUT if the browser/client supports it
    dataType: 'json', // If your request format is JSON
    url: "http://your-api-url", // Your API URL
    headers: {"X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT"}, // You should override this if you used "POST" early X-HTTP-Method-Override set to PUT
    data: '{"username": "theNewUsername"}', // The username/userId of the user who clicked the button
    success: callback, // The JS function which modifies the JSON data by adding the username/userID to the JSON data or by changing all the JSON data to a new one
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a function that does the api request given an id, then bind that function to the div while you're rendering.

```
const apiCall = (id)=>{//actually making api request here};
```

Then when you render the list of divs do something like

```
<div onClick={apiCall.bind(null, id)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do the job with Github's fetch library (https://github.com/github/fetch).

```
// Call the API page
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json')
.then((result) => {
  // Get the result
  // If we want text, call result.text()
  return result.json();
}).then((jsonResult) => {
  // Do something with the result
  console.log(jsonResult);
})
```

For your PUT request with a body, fetch code will look like this :

```
fetch('/apiURL', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2
  })
}
```

I made a live example here with Reddit : https://codepen.io/aamulumi/pen/NAymbW